# /storage/emulated/0 и API31

Tags: java, android

Перечитал много информации по поводу записи файлов в папку /storage/emulated/0. С Андроид 10 ещё понятно, решение есть, а вот с Андроид 12 уже не катит.

Нашёл костыль, в build.gradle указал

```
compileSdkVersion 31
//noinspection OldTargetApi
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Насколько такой костыль может помешать работе ПО? И как всё же без костылей записать файл в папку /storage/emulated/0 в Андроид 12?

Comment: Вам не приходили письма гугла?
C targetSdkVersion = 29 не получиться разместить приложение в гугл маркете. Единственное, что поможет - это разрешение android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE но есть вероятность не пройти модерацию в маркете

Comment: Может и приходили. Я только сейчас начал этим вопросом заниматься

Comment: А вам куда нужно конкретно записывать? И какие файлы.

Comment: В папку свою. Сохраняю данные по работе программы

Comment: А зачем указывать конкретный путь? Пользуй FileOutputStream и система сама назначит куда писать и откуда потом читать этот файл. Или SharedPreference используй, смотря что будешь там хранить

Comment: Попробую, но я переделал на /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/моя программа